# How to transfer data from one table to another in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I thought this would be easy....that will be my famous last words!

I have an access database that is used to keep track of company vehicles. I would like the form used by associates to retain more information that they do not have to see the information populated.  I have created a form (fTripInformation) that will allow them to select the company vehicle used for a work trip from a combo box (CarID). Vehicles are numbered for convenience (1-10).  What I would like to happen is the associate selects the vehicle number from the combo box drop down menu. When that happens the corresponding information associated with the vehicle (Make,Model, Year, Color, etc...) is added to the temp table (tTemp) for this form from the vehicles table (tVehicles). This way the associate only see the vehicle #, yet all the other information will be recorded when the temp table information is transferred to the actual record table.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question(edit)!

Answer (score 0):

This what I did:First, I redefined the Row Source Query the Combobox uses to include all the related information and updated the total Column Count in the Properties Sheet. Then, added the following code:

```
Private Sub CarID_Change()
Dim Rs As Recordset
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tTemp")
Rs.Edit
Rs!CarID = Me.CarID.Column(0)
Rs!Make = Me.CarID.Column(1)
Rs!Model = Me.CarID.Column(2)
Rs!Year = Me.CarID.Column(3)
Rs!Color = Me.CarID.Column(4)
Rs.Update
End Sub

Private Sub CarID_DblClick()
Dim Rs As Recordset
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tTemp")
Rs.Edit
Rs!CarID = ""
Rs!Make = ""
Rs!Model = ""
Rs!Year = ""
Rs!Color = ""
Rs.Update
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This is, in fact, pretty easy!  Download the demo file from the link below and you will have the concept that you described above.  Just modify the code to achieve your specific goals.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/x9cuorenr7r9mi5/AccessAndSQL4_2000.mdb/file